# Damaging Mainboard/CPU with a overhead transparency?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, static-discharge

So yeah.. I recently accidently bent some of my LGA1150 CPU pins and the seller won't replace it, so I have to fix it by my own.

What I'm asking myself is, Can I damage or short out my mainboard by using a overhead transparency? I know that these transparencies are static.

I would use these to press them on the pins to check whether the pin-row is straight and all pins are back in place.

Comment: If you ground yourself it shouldn't be a problem.  By being grounded yourself you would ground the transparency itself.